# displaying openlayer marker

Tags: openlayers

here am using the Google markers and getting up the latitude and longitude values and displaying the Google place markers using open-layer markers here is the piece of code

```
function googleMarker(name, lat, lng, address, types, iconImage)
{       
    var nameLength = name.length;       
    nameLength = nameLength+120;
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( lng ,lat ).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject());                         
    trackMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(20, 20);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -(size.h / 2));                        
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconImage, size, offset);                                        
    map.addLayer(trackMarkers);
    trackMarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat, icon);
    trackMarkers.addMarker(trackMarker);        

    trackMarker.events.register('click', trackMarker, function(evt) 
    {   
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("featurePopup",lonLat, null,'<div style="color:#FF0000;">'+name+","+address + '</div>', null, null);                                       
        map.addPopup(popup);                                    
    });         
}
```

here is the parsed and projected onto the open layer, the issue which i am facing is how to remove the previously enabled popup before selecting the next marker and clicking on the map this popup should get dismissed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to OpenLayers documentation [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.addPopup) you can specify it in your addPopup() call :

> ```
> addPopup: function(popup, exclusive)
> Parameters:    popup        {OpenLayers.Popup}
>                exclusive    {Boolean} If true, closes all other popups first
> ```

So in your case, change your addPopup call in last lines by :

```
map.addPopup(popup, true);
```

**Edit :** If you want to remove all your popups when you click on map, you can do it this way :

```
map.events.register("click", map , function(e){ 
   while(map.popups.length){
      map.removePopup(map.popups[0]);
   } 
});
```

after your map was initialized

Comment: i do have a requirement like on tapping on the map all the popup should disable, could you please tell me how to achieve it

Comment: while( map.popups.length ) {map.removePopup(map.popups[0]);}

Comment: map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
while(map.popups.length){map.removePopup(map.popups[0]);}
}); after your map was initialized